# How do you recursively `scp` files specified by command output?

Tags: shell, glob, scp

I want to `scp` only the files that are tracked in a git repository.

For example, I have the following output from the `git ls-files` command:

```sh
$ git ls-files
someFile
src/file1.txt
src/file2.txt
anotherFile
```

`scp` accepts input like this: `scp someFile src/file1.txt src/file2.txt anotherFile <destination>`, which I can produce by using `scp $(git ls-files) <destination>`. The problem with that is that just dumps all the files into the `<destination>` without maintaining the folder structure. I want to use `scp -r` for this, but I don't know how to filter the files such that only the ones shown with the `git ls-files` command are copied. Perhaps there is some way to use `xargs` for this...

Comment: Note that `scp $(git ls-files) destination` has some serious bugs (unless you turn off globbing and modify `IFS` beforehand -- and even then it's only safe specifically with `git`, which doesn't allow filenames to contain newlines, whereas _in general_ on UNIXy systems newlines are allowed). If your filenames contain spaces or glob characters they'll be split into multiple arguments. This is discussed in part in [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: ...this is something that `xargs -d $'\n'` works around, if you're on a GNU-style system, though it takes some care to use properly in a situation (like this one) where values are substituted into a non-final position; some of the "obvious" and common usage modes have their own security vulnerabilities (_never_ use `xargs -I{} sh -c '...{}...'`).

Answer (score 0):

Use `rsync`.

```
git ls-files | rsync -a --files-from=- . <destination>
```

If not, you can create a `tar` with `--files-from` and use `ssh` with `tar` on the other side.

If not, create a temporary directory, copy all the files there locally while preserving directory structure, and use `scp -r` to copy that temporary directory.

Comment: Only the `tar` version works. `rsync` has the same behavior if invoked the same way, and "copy all the files there while preserving directory structure" is the problem OP had in the first place

Comment: `rsync --relative`, no?